# Unable to obtain complete proto,colinfo,wlan_mgt.tag.interpretation,wlan_mgt.tag.interpretation informatio using tshark

Tags: linux, networking, wireless, wireshark, tshark

I am writing a script to  obtain all the unique SSIDs present around and also some client information.
To do the same I am running the following:

```
tshark -i mon0 -c 100 -z "proto,colinfo,wlan_mgt.tag.interpretation,wlan_mgt.tag.interpretation"
```

This was running fine with tethereal. Tags for SSID, Current channel were displayed.
But I get only the following with tshark :

```
......
wlan_mgt.tag.interpretation == "802.11n (Pre) OUI"
wlan_mgt.tag.interpretation == "802.11n (Pre) HT information"
wlan_mgt.tag.interpretation == "802.11n (Pre) OUI"
wlan_mgt.tag.interpretation == "HT additional information (802.11n D1.00)"
wlan_mgt.tag.interpretation == "Not interpreted"
wlan_mgt.tag.interpretation == "Not interpreted"
.............
```

The above is shown even for beacons where even other tags like SSID and current channel are present.

I am particularly interested in the SSIDs and channel.

I am running this on Backtrack 5 (R3)